# Validation does not work in react-hook-form with dynamic name fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I use `react-hook-form` and `yup-validation`. An array with custom names comes to me from the backend. Validation doesn't work for me. What am I doing

```
export const createValidationSchema = (arr) => {
  const validationObject = {};

  arr?.forEach(({name}) => {
    validationObject[name] = string().required("Required field")
  });

  return object().shape({
    editFields: array()
      .of(object().shape(validationObject))
      .required("Required field")
  });
};

const { control, register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isValid } } = useForm<Form>({
        resolver: yupResolver(createValidationSchema(documentDetail?.template?.items)),
        mode: "onBlur"
    });

    const { fields, append } = useFieldArray<Form>({
        control,
        name: "editFields",
    });
```

below in JSX:

```
{fields?.map(({ name, title, type, id }) => (
    {type === "STRING" && (
        <InputField
            validationType="underlineText"
            {...register(name)}
            required
        />
    )}
)
```

but `errors` always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. In `validationObject` I have an object, and in the schema I assigned it as an array